# Dropshadowfilter on textfield disables the html-links inside. Is there a way around this?

Tags: html, actionscript, textfield

When i put a dropshadowfilter on a dynamic textfield with html-content, the links (a href) stop working.The textfields rotate in flash 3D space so they have a transformmatrix applied to them. Could this be the reason? Anybody had problems with html-links and dropshadowfilter applied to the textfield? it makes no difference if you put the filter on the textfield itself or the movieclip container around it...

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix ... simply target the textfield within the mc and set rotationX and rotationY = 0 !!

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried it in 2 ways and they both worked.

1.using a movie clip as a container
I created a dynamic text field
I embedded the characters, set html to true, set the htmlText with a link...
then placed all that inside a movie clip which I rotated in 3D.

Tried it and it worked.

2.not using a movie clip as a container.
I created the dynamic text field, embedded characters and all of the above except
placing it all inside a movie clip.
I just rotated the text field in 3d using the transform matrix like you mentioned.

```
//my text field is called 'label'
label.htmlText = '<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a>';
var m3d:Matrix3D = new Matrix3D();
m3d.appendRotation(30,Vector3D.Y_AXIS);
label.transform.matrix3D = m3d;
```

This worked as well.
Hope it helps